# Linear hashing split policy (load factor )

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, disk

I am trying to insert 1000 keys in a hash table (using linear hashing algorithm) in order to count the average disk accesses. I also want to do this test for various load factor limits (e.g. 50% and 80%). I found the following code for linear hashing: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Hash_Tables#A_Java_implementation_of_linear_hashing 

I can't understand how the load factor is set in this code. Does it use a default factor of 75%? How can I change this parameter to 80%?

Thanks.

Comment: The link you provided states that HashMap uses linear hashing. I would just create these with different load factors. If you don't know how to use a class I suggest you read its Javadoc, that is what it is for.

Comment: Is the class HashMap appropriate for what I am looking for? As the article states this is for extendible hashing. Anyway, can you be more specific? Also, there is no documentation for LHMap2 class.

Comment: It is not clear to me what disk access and hashing or load factors have to do with one another.  In general you want to access a disk sequentially to maximise performance, even for SSD.  Hashing randomises placement of data to avoid collisions and not appropriate for modelling disks.  The load factor is the point at which a hash collection must grow, but disks don't grow dynamically so load factor don't apply to disks either.

Comment: Looking at LHMap2...I have no idea what it's doing, frankly.

Comment: OK then, can you suggest me another link with code for linear hashing?